# Global Address Lookups on Samsung Email app

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, exchange, active-sync, samsung-email

I have set up my Exchange Mail using the default Samsung Email app. Mail and calendars work great, but I am not able to do Global Address lookups.

Is this possible? How can do this?

Answer (score 0):

So what I've discovered so far,

Android doesn't have this functionality yet and you'll need to install a 3rd-party app to get this. An app that I found works is 'Swift Contacts'.

What's nice is I am able to type the name of the person right in the 'To:' field and it does a lookup and completes the email address. The only problem is I think this app will stop working after a period of time if you don't pay for it. I haven't found a free alternative for it.

Comment: It'd be better if you could provide the link of the app on Play Store. Just now, I couldn't find the app you mentioned.